# Require Help in detecting variants for #Bigcommerce platform

Tags: bigcommerce

We have an old questions which we have addressed to #Bigcommerce Support Department, but still haven't received a reply.

In our [In Stock reminder](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/in-stock-reminder-back-in-stock-alerts/) app we faced a problem related to Stencil theme. On product page for detecting of variant selection we used hook `'product-options-change-remote'` and added our own handler of this event in the following way:

```
 window.stencilUtils.hooks.on('product-options-change-remote', function(data) {
var options = data.response.data;
... other code here ...
});
```

This code worked in the past. Now in our clients' shops we see that the code is not working because `window.stencilUtils` object doesn't exist there.

Comment: Have you checked Developers Console to see if another script is broken, preventing stencilUtils from being instantiated in window scope? Have you looked at what scripts are loading into the page?

Comment: @eon of course we&#39;ve checked this.
Moreover this worked in the past, but not available to be used for now.